# Как найти родительский блок?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

На странице есть текст, который обернут в заранее не известный div блок.

И у меня есть строка(часть текста) которая соответствует началу текста который на странице.

Вопрос, как определить название класса родительского элемента в который обернут нужный мне текст?

Comment: Использовали phpQuery?

Comment: там же написано // Find all text blocks $es = $html->find('text'); затем parent() https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm

Comment: @Jean-Claude, вопрос в том, что заранее не известно, в каком элементе нужно искать текст.  Ваш пример ищет текстовый блок в конкретном элементе и будет игнорировать остальные.

Answer (score 0):

Узнать название класса родительского элемента можно с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
    $html = '<html><body>
        Hello <div class="asdasd">crazy</div> <div class="asdasd"><i></i> world</div>!
    </body></html>';
    
    // определяем название класса родительского элемента слова "world"
    preg_match("~
        <(?'tag'\w*)[^>]*?(?:class=['\"](?'class_name'[0-9a-z-_]+?)['\"])[^>]*?>
        .*?(".preg_quote('world').").*? # world - поисковый запрос
        </\k'tag'>
    ~isx", $html, $matches);
    
    $matches = array_filter($matches, "is_string", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    /*
    print_r($matches);
    Array
    (
        [tag] => div
        [class_name] => asdasd
    )
    */
```

Ниже информация не относится к вопросу, но показывает, как можно найти остальной текст, у которого родительский элемент имеет найденный тег $matches['tag'] и класс $matches['class_name']. Это можно сделать с помощью тех же регулярок или simple_html_dom:

```
    $DOM = new simple_html_dom();
    $DOM->load($html, true, false);
    $text = $DOM->find("{$matches['tag']}[class='{$matches['class_name']}'] text");
    foreach($text as $e)
        $all_text[] = trim($e->outertext);
    /*
    print_r($all_text);die;
    Array
    (
        [0] => crazy
        [1] => world
    )
    */
```